# Jmeter- writing run time data to csv(column) file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am running a test with a loop and  want to capture the session of the test and write it to a CSV column( not row) during run 
Eg
Run1: ses1
Run2:ses2
Run 3: se3

CSV
Ses1, ses2, ses 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any of the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) use the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
new File('/path/to/your/file.csv') << vars.get('session') << ','
```

Replace `session` with the actual name of the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding your session.